# Optimistic locking: modifying a resource using another resources

Tags: rest, etag

*Sample use case*: The user modifies a cooking recipe (resource C) using actual list of products (resource LP/ list of resources P). Both resources C and LP may be changed concurrently by other users. Any of product in the list (P) may be changed, too. If any of those resources have been changed, the client should have correspondent errors in response of modifying PUT.

*The question*: What is best practices to ensure that the user uses unchanged data when changes the recipe? Can we use ETag (RFC 7232) method to enforce concurrent access rules? If not, how we can modify the API structure or use another method to implement it? My problem is how I can use ETags from multiple resources to enforce the RFC.

And I understand that in this particular case we can just use POST to add the products one-by-one etc. But in real life it can be complicated cases, consider a builder from several collections or resources, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please do so! You need to compare the ETag that gets passed up as part of the request (in the `If-Match` header) with the ETag of the server's current representation. If they match, go ahead and update the value. If they don't, return a `412 Precondition Failed`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Eric. My problem is how I can use ETags from multiple resources to enforce the RFC.

Comment: You're making a PUT call. The body of the PUT is the new state of the resource. The ETag is tied to that resource. If you're embedding subresources in the body of the PUT, then the ETag for the resource has to include the state of the subresources also.